# Postgres: increasing the bdr.max_databases variable fails

Tags: database, postgresql, replication, postgresql-9.4, postgresql-bdr

I'm currently encountering an issue regarding a BDR'd postgres database. Specifically, the maximum amount of databases allowed within a bdr cluster. 
According to the logs, I need to increase the value held by bdr.max_databases

running `postgres=# ALTER SYSTEM SET bdr.max_databases = '64';` seems to fail with: 
`ERROR:  unrecognized configuration parameter "bdr.max_databases"`

I'm unable to find any documentation on this variable so I'm somewhat lost.

Is there a way to set the value of bdr.max_databases?

Postgre version: **(PostgreSQL) 9.4.14**

Original error:

```
2018-08-08 14:04:55 GMT d=db p=45359 a=bdr (6467878782116338286,1,33381,): perdb ERROR:  Too many databases BDR-enabled for bdr.max_databases
2018-08-08 14:04:55 GMT d=db p=45359 a=bdr (6467878782116338286,1,33381,): perdb HINT:  Increase bdr.max_databases above the current limit of 61
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting it in postgresql.conf, rather than ALTER SYSTEM? I'm not sure that ALTER SYSTEM handles configuration parameters that are added by extensions.